# Sybase connectivity with iphone

Tags: iphone, sup

I am developing sample app for iPad in which I am trying to pull data from SUP.I followed all the steps given in document "Developer Reference for iOS
Sybase Unwired Platform 1.5.5 (sup_devref_iOS.pdf)" but still I am getting error `Xcode could not locate source file: SUPAbstractDB.m`.I have given the path of three libraries libClientrt.a, libMO.a, libSUPObj.a in header search path.But still I am getting this error.Can know why I am getting this error?Please can anyone help I am struggling on this for 2 days.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would venture to guess, without knowing your project configuration, that these files you have added lie outside the project hierarchy. Even though you've set the path I've had problems when I have dependencies that lie outside of $SRCROOT. Hope that helps.